# How can I get my copy of Murder to play?

Tags: emulation, murder

I've got a ROM of Rabbit Software's 1983 classic, Murder. I've got it as a .t64 file, what do I need in order to play it?

Comment: Sneaky. Very sneaky.

Comment: I know who I'm voting for in the upcoming election.

Comment: Did I just spend my time answering a troll question? Thanks...

Comment: @JohnoBoy not really, see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2190/2259

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need a ZX Spectrum emulator, a quick Google search lead me to [this page](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/emulators.html) which list multiple emulators by platform. I can't tell which emulator is better, but your can check their [stat page](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/emustats.html) and see what's popular by platform.